# Codeigniter model - query all rows in a table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

I'm having a few issues trying to query all rows from a database using codeigniter.

As i understand it, to query all rows you should be able to do this

```
$invoices_object = $this->db->get('invoices');
```

or

```
$invoices_object = $this->db->query('SELECT * from invoices');
```

But neither work.

This does

```
$invoices_object = $this->db->get('invoices', 5000);
```

But once i increase it above 5000 rows, it breaks.

I am querying the db and exporting to csv via fputcsv.

By break, I mean I am getting a 404 error, and undefined in the address bar.

But like i said it works absolutely fine below 5000 records, but i need to just select all.

I have the php memory limit set to -1, and execution time is set high also?

Anything im missing?

Comment: First, I would get fputcsv out of the loop and see how it goes. Does CI breaks if you just make the query and display the results ? Are there some BLOB type columns in 'invoices' ?

Comment: Nope, all columns are simple text, very simple data and columns.

Comment: Commented out fputcsv and tried to just echo, still breaks

Comment: Sounds trivial, but... Did you put an "exit;" as well? Did you try to copy-paste your query in phpmyadmin ("SQL" tab)? What does it say? I don't know your working environment, but it would help if you have access to the php_error.log file.

Comment: ok good thinking. Checked error log, PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 33554432 bytes. but its set to -1?

Comment: Did you try with an M (Megabytes) value ? Try editing your php.ini file by setting "memory_limit = 64M" for starters. Then increment (128M, 256M...) and see what happens.

Comment: yeah i just set it through whm to 256M, but its still giving he same error? wtf

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54751/discussion-between-bonatoc-and-frobak).